# Continuous horizontal scrolling

Tags: android

I'm learning animation and scrolling features in android. I have a HorizontalLayout containing 
LeniarLayout. Here is my code.

```
LinearLayout layOut = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnLayout);                   
        ImageView im1= new ImageView(this);        
        im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.im1);
        ImageView im2= new ImageView(this);
        im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.im2);
        ImageView im3= new ImageView(this);
        im3.setImageResource(R.drawable.im3);
        ImageView im4= new ImageView(this);
        im4.setImageResource(R.drawable.im4);
        ImageView im5= new ImageView(this);
        im5.setImageResource(R.drawable.im5);
        ImageView im6= new ImageView(this);
        im6.setImageResource(R.drawable.im6);

        layOut.addView(im1,0);
        layOut.addView(im2,1);
        layOut.addView(im3,2);
        layOut.addView(im4,3);
        layOut.addView(im5,4);
        layOut.addView(im6,5);
```

I'm trying to make these image to autoscroll continously and in definitely. 
I looked at Scroller class but it seems only TextView can use Scroller class, since no other class has setScroller method. 
What is the other way to achieve continous scrolling for in-definite period of time.

Comment: Horizontal scrolling is the devil! That said, could you provide a little context as to why you want to implement this?

Comment: Bascially i want to implement a horizontal scrolling ticker containing images . My idea was .. if i can scroll 5-6 image views continously across the screen then i can put my graphics in any of those component so that the image appears to float across the screen. As soon as image disappears from screen that component can contain a new image and then the scrolling continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options I can think of.  One, draw your images to a `Canvas` and fake a scroll movement via the `onTouchEvent` method.  Then you just draw the images over and over as the user "scrolls."

Edit: removed option 2.  That works for vertical scrolling only and I forgot you specified horizontal.

Comment: Hi pls share the Option 2 also. I need to scroll vertical also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to re-use the [Gallery](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) widget? It should contain everything u need + it's adapter based so you could make a adapter that allows indefinite scrolling.

UI wise you can adjust it as well.

Comment: But how do you set it to autoscroll mode?

Comment: Hm, still go with the Gallery, but try to call this method: `onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)`, then you could simulate it. I would do it with a repeating `TimerTask`.